# Bootstrap dropdown not opening first click on React 16

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

Using the following: Bootstrap 4.0.0-beta.2, popper.js 1.13.0, and React 16.0.0. I have multiple dropdown buttons in my React app and on first clicks they don't open. After the first click they work as expected and open and close on first click. Any ideas?

```
<div className="dropdown">
    <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary btn-xs dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Edit</button>
    <div className="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
        <Link role="button" className="dropdown-item text-sm" to={path1}>Click me</Link>
        <Link role="button" className="dropdown-item text-sm" to={path2}>Click me</Link>
        <Link role="button" className="dropdown-item text-sm" to={path3}>Click me</Link>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is how I load in app.jsx

```
//load bootstrap and app css
import Popper from 'popper.js';
window.Popper = Popper;
import 'bootstrap';
import 'style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader!applicationStyles';
```

and this is how I load bootstrap, jQuery and popper.js in my webpack.config.js file

```
entry: [
    'script-loader!jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
    'script-loader!popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js',
    'script-loader!bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js',
    'babel-polyfill',
    './app/app.jsx',
],
externals: {
    jQuery: 'jQuery'
},
plugins: [
    // new BundleAnalyzerPlugin(),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        '$': 'jQuery',
        'jQuery': 'jQuery',
        Popper: ['popper.js', 'default'],
    }),
```

I tried adding `$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()` to the onClick and that didn't work either

**Solution** Turns out I had loaded Bootstrap twice using both the entry in webpack.config.js file and the `import 'bootstrap'` statement in app.jsx so I commented out `import 'bootstrap'` and it works

Comment: plugins array is not closed.

Comment: @1stthomas thanks for the comment - I just included a subsection of the webpack.config.js file to keep the code to a minimum. It is closed in the full version

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You may have jQuery or Bootstrap included twice. I don't use React, but I was having the same problem with Angular. It turns out that I was including jQuery/Bootstrap in my index.html as well my "scripts" configuration (which I think would be your "entry").

Comment: Thanks Luis - turns out I had loaded Bootstrap twice

Comment: This solved my issue, someone had included both `bootstrap.js` _and_ `bootstrap.bundle.js`

Comment: Fixed the issue for me. Thanks

Comment: Just like the other posters above: I had added Bootstrap javascript reference twice. Removed it and everything worked nicely.

Answer (score 5):

You should import this line and Test again :

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle';
```

this work for me like a charm :)

Answer (score 4):

I got the same issue. I noticed that when i was using **bootstrap.min.js** and **jquery.min.js** at a same time. Then my dropdown takes two click for toggle in first time after page load. Then i commented **bootstrap.min.js**. Now it is not giving me this issue. Try this. Maybe it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

In my case the problem was: i had both libraries at same time

> bootstrap and bootstrap.bundle

i just left bootstrap.bundle and it's working.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same issue recently, I solved it by writing custom script:

```
<div class="filter-dropdown text-right">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Edit</button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
     <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a>
     <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a>
     <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>



$(".filter-dropdown").on("click", ".dropdown-toggle", function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().addClass("show");
    $(this).attr("aria-expanded", "true");
    $(this).next().addClass("show"); 
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you included **bootstrap.min.js** and **jQuery.js** you have to comment one. I suggest you comment **bootstrap.min.js** and if you need the library for any special purpose you have to include it separately.